# Unable to get pop up in Windows Server 2003 machine

Tags: c#, popup, windows-services, windows-server-2003

I have a service and a Form application. In that, I am calling the Form Application using my Windows service. I have tested it on Windows 7 and it works fine for that, which means it shows pop up via calling Windows service as expected. But when I run the same thing on Windows Server 2003, it somehow doesn't show my Form Application when I run my Windows service.

I am unable to determine the cause of this here and would appreciate any help or guidance that can spread more light on this.

Comment: Why are you mixing UI and services?

Comment: It is my requirement. Please answer if you know

Comment: Have you looked at the event log to see if there are any error produced, are you catching any exceptions when showing the form and outputting them somewhere to review?

Comment: Actually it works perfect on Windows 7, but when I start it on Windows Server 2003 it doesn't give output/error

Comment: Impossible to answer without even knowing at least part of the code.

Comment: Exactly why you should look for errors. If it works on one platform and not on another, somewhere something is going wrong, generally that can produce an error.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar Please see url for complete code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23176/Create-a-system-tray-icon-and-a-dialog-for-a-Windo

Answer (score 0):

First, check the Task Manager's Processes tab to confirm that your service's executable is indeed running. If it isn't then heed the advice already given and check the Event Log.

Second, ensure that you are logging in to Session 0 (the console session) when you connect to your Windows Server 2003 box. If using RDP, add the "/admin" (or "/console") flag to get to Session 0.